# Replacing a line in Python by reading text file

Tags: python

I have saved a varible in my text based game for the players position.

```
def Save():
    savefile = open('save.txt','w')
    savefile.write(str(currentLocation)+'\n')
    savefile.close()
    print("GAME SAVED!", file=sys.stderr)
```

This works and the text file only has the number 3 in it.

Now I am trying to load that file to replace the number in my player position varible which looks like...

```
currentLocation = 0
```

So after I load the file into the game I want the 0 to be replaced with the number from the text file so it will look like.

```
currentLocation = 3
```

Currently my Load function looks like

```
def Load():
savefile = open('save.txt', 'r')
for line in savefile:
    currentLocation.append(currentLocation)
savefile.close()
```

Which I know is wrong as I have only been taught how to load and replace lists.

Comment: if you are calling a variable assignment such as (`x = 1`) as *"replacing a line in Python"* then you should read a [Python book for complete beginners](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide/NonProgrammers). Otherwise, you'll be stumped by trivial tasks. A couple of hours of reading can save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "currentLocation" as global variable to change it inside a load-function:

```
def Load():
    global currentLocation
    with open ("save.txt", "r") as myfile:
        currentLocation = int(myfile.read())
    print "GAME LOADED!"
```

If you want to load lists, it depends on how you saved them. A simple possibility is to save each list entry in a new row like this:

```
def saveVisited():
    global visitedLocations
    with open ("save.txt", "w") as myfile:
        for each in visitedLocations:
            myfile.write(str(each) +'\n')
    print("GAME SAVED!")
```

After that you can read in the list by going line by line and discarding the `'\n'`:

```
def loadVisited():
    global visitedLocations
    with open ("save.txt", "r") as myfile:
        visitedLocations = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in myfile]
    print "GAME LOADED!"
```

Another possibility is e.g.:

```
def saveVisited():
    global visitedLocations
    with open ("save.txt", "w") as myfile:
        myfile.write(str(visitedLocations))
    print("GAME SAVED!")

from ast import literal_eval    
def Load():
    global currentLocation
    with open ("save.txt", "r") as myfile:
        currentLocation = list(literal_eval(myfile.read()))
    print "GAME LOADED!"
```

Comment: OMG! Thank You been stuck on this for days!

Comment: You should also use the "with" (open ...) keyword in your save-function. It is shorter and has the advantage that the file is properly closed automatically after its suite finishes.

Comment: I am trying to do the same thing with a 2nd save file for a variable which looks like. VisitedLocations =[0], I take it, this method wont work for lists?

Comment: Just make some adjustments for lists. It depends on how you save them, see my edit in the answer.

Comment: This method seems to save it into one number on each line instead of a list.

Comment: Yes, that is what I wrote. The load function reads each line and puts everything in a list again. It is just an example on how you can deal with this. If you want to save the list as it is, see my second edit.